# Error when trying to build anything after installing Xcode 3.2.3

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-snow-leopard, installation, upgrade

I just recently installed the latest verson of Xcode as well as the ios 4.0.2 sdk with the disk image downloaded off of the apple developer site named xcode_3.2.3_andios_4.0.2.dmg. My past version of xcode came off of the snow leopard install disk. After the install I get an error when I try to build anything including a new project that states :

error: can't exec '/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2' (No such file or directory)

Does anybody have any ideas as to what went wrong and how I can get Xcode working again?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the UNIX development files and programs that should be installed when you install Xcode?  Re-run the Xcode installer and make sure they are selected.

If you find the "Installation" section in the "About Xcode and iPhone SDK" PDF (in the disk image, along side the installer package itself) you'll see reference to the files you're missing:

> UNIX Development. Command-line tools used for UNIX-based development. Its components are always placed in /usr - only one version installed at a time.